# Let $f$ be continuous and nonnegative on $[a,b]$. Show that $ \exists c \in [a,b] $ with $f(c)=( \frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b} f^2)^.5$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f$ be continuous and nonnegative on $[a,b]$. Show that $\exists c \in [a,b]$  with $f(c)=( \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} f^2)^.5$

This is my attempt: Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ , by Mean Value Thm for Integrals, $ \exists c \in [a,b]$ with $\int_{a}^{b} f =f(c)(b-a)$ Divide by $(b-a)$ since $b \neq a $, we get $f(c)= \frac{1}{(b-a)} \int_{a}^{b} f$.

Now I am having trouble showing that $f(c)=( \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} f^2)^.5$

Comment: What about applying the mean value theorem for integrals to $g = f^2$?

Answer (score 3):

$f$ is continuous at $[a,b]\implies$

$ f^2$ continuous at $[a,b]$ and by Mvt,

$$\exists c\in[a,b]\;:\; \int_a^bf^2=(b-a)f^2(c)$$

thus $$|f(c)|=f(c)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** As $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$, it attains its minimum and maximum at say $m$ and $M$. So
\begin{align}
f(m)=\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(m)^2dx\right)^{1/2}\leq&\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)^2dx\right)^{1/2}\\ \leq&\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(M)^2dx\right)^{1/2}=f(M)
\end{align}